# How do I properly pluralise Wicket validation messages?

Tags: java, internationalization, wicket

We have some custom validation messages in our top-level web application resource bundle:

```
StringValidator.range=${label} must be between ${minimum} and ${maximum} characters long.
StringValidator.minimum=${label} must be at least ${minimum} characters long.
StringValidator.maximum=${label} must be at most ${maximum} characters long.
```

A review of the code for missing plural formats notified me that we had forgotten to properly pluralise the "characters" here. My first thought was, "maybe characters can never be 1", but then I realised that only English has such naïve plural rules and that our Arabic localisation would probably suffer if we didn't fix this.

So I went looking for how it formats the text and eventually it ends up inside `FormComponent#getString` - and it looks like the built-in Wicket formatting for error messages can't do proper plurals after all. The string interpolation code it's using is literally only good enough to interpolate the values into the string, it doesn't have anything along the lines of `MessageFormat`.

So what I'm wondering is - is there an elegant way to slot `MessageFormat` in for these and other validation error messages?

I already know that I can rewrite the entire `StringValidator` to get custom message formats, but that seems like a lot of work just to change some strings.

Comment: `StringValidator.minimum=${label} must be at least ${minimum} character(s) long.` :)

Comment: @tetsuo 1. yuck. 2. Even that isn't convenient in all languages because in some cases there are more plural forms.